# Create sub arrays of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

What is the best and most resource efficient way to create sub-arrays of an array? I have an array of objects as follow:

```
bigArray = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Marc",
        age: 29
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Caroline",
        age: 27
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "John",
        age: 30
    }];
```

And I would like to generate 3 sub-arrays such as

- ids = [1, 2, 3]
- names = ["Marc", "Caroline", "John"]
- ages = [29, 27, 30]

I have tried with nested "for" loops and experimented it with a map() method but I'm not convinced this is the cleanest way. Especially since I may have dozens of parameters for every object (i.e. "last name, city, car...)

Comment: You only need one loop. Parse the json objects one by one and extract the data. It's O(n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all objects have the same keys in your array, I'd do it this way :

```js
bigArray = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Marc",
        age: 29
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Caroline",
        age: 27
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "John",
        age: 30
    }];

let output = {}

Object.keys(bigArray[0]).forEach( key => {
 output[key+"s"] = bigArray.map( obj => obj[key] ) 
})

// Or as a one-liner, to show off to your friends
Object.keys(bigArray[0]).forEach( key => output[key+"s"] = bigArray.map( obj => obj[key] ))

console.log(output)
```

Then you acces the data with `output.names`, `output.ages`

Comment: `output` does not have a properties called `names` or `ages`.

Comment: That's right, code updated. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, exactly what I was looking for. I was worried foreach loops would be quite consuming on a big array but I'm happy to see that this is your recommendation

Comment: Well there's no real way around it. The thing is to optimize the code as best as possible. For instance, one of the earlier answers here was computing the object's keys in each loop, resulting in an inefficient code. Here I'm only computing the keys once.